How to make a map field shared across multiple messages in protobuf code generated in C++?
I have multiple downstream clients consuming a single map field. The map field is large and may introduces extra performance issues on unintended copying.
message ToClientAReq {
    ...
    map<int64, Value> my_map = N1;
}

message ToClientBReq {
    ...
    map<int64, Value> my_map = N2;
}


However, the generated code results in each message owning its map field. So, I have to copy the map multiple times when assigning to each request object although they are always identical.
How to justify my .proto file or my code generator to enable the map field sharing?

Create a separate message with only the map?

@Jarod42 So a sub message object can be shared across its different parent messages?

I don't say it is shared. If your message has both ToClientAReq and ToClientBReq, then move the map in a higher level. if there are send individually, then extra message to map some id to the map, and then use that id instead of the map in those message.

In short, you have to restructure your message to expose only once the map.

optional map might be used, so if map is not present, use the other map (You have to do it manually in your reader/writer though).

@Jarod42 I'd thought about this. It seems theres two problems with the method. One is restructuring introduces to many changes across different projects which is not realistic. Another one is that it seeems non sense to include ToClientAReq message when sending a request to client B, even if it's empty

It is still unclear to me how you send message(s). Is there a bigger message where those messages are included, or do you send message individually? if send individually, how do you expect to retrieve that common map?

@Jarod42 I send messages individually. The common map comes from another downstream service. Currently I'm thinking about manually serialization and send message with a serialized map. Then I deserialize the map at downstream services. This approach seems also saves the time of repeated serialization on the same map. But it requires some extra manual operations.

If message are individual, you have either to send the whole map, or some id of a map that client can retrieve from elsewhere (as previous dedicated message to register the map).

You could probably swap the map in and out of each message right before/after serializing (google::protobuf::Map has a swap() method). This would allow you to only store it once, but you would still pay the cost of serializing it multiple times.

@IgorTandetnik makes sense. That's indeed a solution. Move the map in, serialize,  and then move it out
